# googleapis geocode return only one record for incomplete or ambiguous address

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geocode, street-address

I want to normalize (server-side), an input address, and it could be incomplete or complete.

Which APIs should I use?

I have used geocode, place/autocomplete and place/textsearch APIs, but I don't get what I want.

Incomplete address input example:

"via andrea roma" in Rome there are more streets with "andrea" word.

With geocode and palce/textsearch return 1 records. Why?

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=VIA)via andrea roma&region=it&language=it

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=VIAvia andrea roma&region=it&language=it

With autocomplete is ok because return more address.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=via andrea Roma&region=it&language=it

**BUT** if I always use place/autocomplete API, it is incorrect when the address is complete, because return more address.

Complete address input example:

"via andrea doria 1 roma" in Rome exist 1 addres with this name.

With geocode and palce/textsearch return 1 records and is ok

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=via Andrea doria 1 roma&region=it&language=it

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=via andrea doria 1 ROMA&region=it&language=it

BUT with autocompleate return more address. Why?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=via andrea doria 1 Roma&region=it&language=it

So I don't understand which API I should use to normalize my address into my c# library

Help me! Thanks

Chiara

Answer (score -1):

[Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) is a web service that returns place predictions in response to an HTTP request, means it may return  more than one results as it is designed to cope with ambiguous queries.

On the other hand, [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) converts specific addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739). This is the reason why it is only returning one result.

As for the [Places Text Search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text), it usually returns information about a set of places based on a string. For example, your given Places Text Search API web request, which is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=VIAvia andrea roma&region=it&language=it&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

returns 4 different places in the response. These are:

- `Via Annia Regilla, 27/29, 00178 Roma RM` (ChIJu76VeZOJJRMR3CjFz4Y-Fd4)
- `Via di Sant'Andrea delle Fratte, 9, 00187 Roma RM` (ChIJ2UYsr1RgLxMRnVSDeOy_ZLg)
- `Via di Grottarossa, 1035/1039, 00189 Roma RM` (ChIJe7tWFQRnLxMRmG6wWxAD-vc)
- `Via Alberto Cadlolo, 101, 00136 Roma RM` (ChIJHw9AUoRgLxMR5jT9M_JvJeQ)

To choose between Places Autocomplete API (may return more than one result) and Geocoding API (returns only one result) depends on your use-case and implementation.